# Virtual machine is restored to original on restart

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I wanted to create a Linux VM using Oracle VM Virtual box. The problem is that as soon as I restart the VM it restores to it original state. This is what I don't want as I lose all the test results for which I had created the VM.

Virtual Box does let me take snapshots periodically but I don't want to use snap shots.

What I am looking for is that once I create a VM I should be able to use it as a physical Linux machine. Is there a way to configure Virtual Box to prevent it from restoring the VM to it's original form.

Comment: Did you run the OS installation in VirtualBox, or did you just run it as a virtual LiveCD instance?

Comment: Interestingly, I didn't install the Linux. Virtual Box just asks for the Boot media, it doesn't ask if you want to install the OS :-(

Answer (score 0):

check that virtualbox is not setting the VM as 'immutable' that is, reverting it back to the initial state once it is shut down. while useful at times, i could see how an immutable image could be causing you trouble if it's not the desired effect.

Check the link for some more info.

[Understanding and Configuring Virtualbox Hard Disks](http://www.virtuatopia.com/index.php/Understanding_and_Configuring_VirtualBox_Virtual_Hard_Disks)